# Change gtk theme for X11 apps

Tags: applications, homebrew, x11

I am using Zim note app http://zim-wiki.org in Ubuntu and I want to use the same in my OS X.

So I've installed Zim and can launch it through X11 from menu. But all GTK apps look ugly: bad fonts w/o antialiasing  etc, standard theme looks terrible

[image]

Is it any way to change it to any not so bad theme? (Ideally to yosemite like)

I use brew but I don't know package name for that (if it exist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy one of the themes (from gnome-look or etc) to /Users/your_user/.themes and install gtk-chtheme via brew. There you can set theme which you want:

[image]

So now Zim looks as follow:

[image]

Comment: I can't get this to work. (I'm actually here because of Zim too). Can you provide more details with an example theme?